# Magento 2 run custom PHP script

Tags: magento2, php

I want to run a **custom PHP script** in **Magento 2 webshop** using a **custom module**.

But I want it to run only when installing or during installation of my **custom  module**.

To be specific, during **`setup:upgrade command`** and will trigger only once except if there's a change in my **custom module version**.

Anyone tried that before?
Can you point me into right direction on how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP `shell_exec()` command for your requirement.

You can execute `shell_exec()` command in Install or Upgrade Schema of module. So when your module is installed or you change module version your code will be executed.

If it is not standalone PHP script then another approach would be to Just execute your Module's functions in Install script.

Find below example to execute shell script

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
    SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        if(version_compare($version1, $version2)){
            //execute your script here
            shell_exec('base_path/scriptname.php'); // this will execute custom php script at given location
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you site an example , I mean a sample code on implementation

Comment: @magefms example included

Comment: let me check. I'll update you later

Comment: is base_path dynamic or static? should i change it ?

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: I'll check again but using installschema

Comment: @magefms base_path is dynamic and you can use installschema if you're installing module first time in magento otherwise use upgradeschema

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want exactly but according to your description, You may use magento default InstallSchema feature to achieve this.

Like if you create a module, and create following file.

File: [Vendor]/[Module]/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        // Your php script code here

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

You may execute your code in between, which will only be executed while only installation of your module.

Comment: I'll check first

Comment: You want to execute php file through shell scripting ?